# In Discord.JS what is the diffrence between GatewayIntentBits and IntentBits.Flag?

Tags: discord.js

Been working on a discord bot for a while now, and I am still unsure about the difference between GatewayIntentBits and IntentBits.Flag for declaring a new Client in discord.js. I have my code working, but I am curious to know the difference between the two. Any help would be excellent :) thank you in advance.

Comment: Where did you find `IntentBits`?

Answer (score 1):

*I'm assuming by `IntentBits` you meant `IntentsBitField` because of how you mentioned the "Flags" property and I've seen that method used before*

`GatewayIntentBits` provides just the flags you can refer to and nothing else. `IntentsBitField` is a special structure in discord.js that allows you to *modify* a bitfield, using functions like `add()` and `remove()`. Here's an example from [the discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#the-intents-bitfield):

```js
const { Client, IntentsBitField } = require('discord.js');

const myIntents = new IntentsBitField();
myIntents.add(IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildPresences, IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers);

const client = new Client({ intents: myIntents });
```

If you just need to decide which one to use to set the intents of your bot, I don't believe there's a difference - except GatewayIntentBits is fewer characters to type :)